# strange ng-model behaviour (ng-model mapped to array element)

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

What should be the right behaviuor when you have a `ng-model` declaration like this one?

```
data-ng-model="elements[0]"
```

The way it works, if `elements` is already defined in the scope as an array, it works as I'd expected assigning the first element of the array.

But if `elements` is not declared it assigns this value :

```
elements = {0:'anyvalue'}
```

(which makes sense if I'd had written `data-ng-model="elements['0']"`)

In this case :

```
elements[0]='anyvalue';
elements['0']='anyvalue';
```

and I cannot read the value of the propery using "dot" notation (`elements.0` or `elements.'0'`).

So it looks correct, but a bit weird.

Is this behaviour correct, or it should instantiate an array when the scope variable is not defined?

Comment: It is correct. The short version is that in JS everything (excluding primitives, but including arrays) is an object, and that is valid object notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array is just a special type of object. If you look at an array in a debugger, all of the values are listed as properties with numeric keys, like the one you show. If you don't initialize the object as an array, it would still accesses the object in the same way, which just means you now have an object with numeric keys and none of the helpful functions from the Array prototype.

Comment: thx for the answer, but then should I be able to access the value using <object>.<property> notation?

Comment: Not really. Number values are not valid key names for dot notation, nor can key names begin with numbers (if I remember correctly). You can use variable[0] or variable ['0'] though.